Stripe promocode: how to verify that user have redeemed the promocode before or not
I have a Django project configured with Stripe for payments. I have created promocodes for discounts, which can only be redeemed once per customer. The problem is that I want to validate whether a given customer has already redeemed a specific promocode. If they haven't redeemed it, I want to proceed to the next step; otherwise, I want to stop the customer at that point.
I have retrieve the promocode but it returns the following values:
{
  "active": true,
  "code": "test10",
  "coupon": {
    "amount_off": null,
    "created": 1716289929,
    "currency": "usd",
    "duration": "once",
    "duration_in_months": null,
    "id": "test10",
    "livemode": false,
    "max_redemptions": null,
    "metadata": {},
    "name": null,
    "object": "coupon",
    "percent_off": 10.0,
    "redeem_by": null,
    "times_redeemed": 1,
    "valid": true
  },
  "created": 1716289930,
  "customer": null,
  "expires_at": 1716595200,
  "id": "promo_1PIqc2B67hjAZnF4umv6pZCP",
  "livemode": false,
  "max_redemptions": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "object": "promotion_code",
  "restrictions": {
    "first_time_transaction": true,
    "minimum_amount": null,
    "minimum_amount_currency": null
  },
  "times_redeemed": 1
}

I am not able to find an API that validates whether a customer has already redeemed a given promocode.
I'm expecting a method or API endpoint in Stripe that allows me to check if a specific customer (customer ID) has redeemed a specific promocode.
I have created The promocode which is only be redeemed once per customer.

You would need to either:

create individual one-time Promotion Code objects for each customer, and then list them by customer and code (in case you want to use the same code) to check if it was used, or
update Customer's metadata field, to record if a given promo code was used.


Thanks, Vanya. I have added the metadata field with stripe.Customer.modify and retrieve metadata details to verify if any promocode was used before or not.
